# Error 500 Controller CommunityPhotosController not found!

Tags: joomla-2.5, jomsocial

I have this error on my joomla installation and I'm not able to see what's causing the problem.

I've been googling but there's not much information about this error. I've found that it might be something to do with jomsocial and went to the post forum that they have: http://www.jomsocial.com/forum/photos-videos/13650-can-t-open-images-500-error 
but I'm not able to see the response because Im not a member :(.

I also disabled all the Jomsocial components in the extension manager but nothing.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You have an extension installed which is loading properly.  The components name is CommunityPhotos, one I haven't heard of off the top of my head; if this is a third party controller you installed I would disable and contact developer.  If not sure, go to the menu item handling this view and let us know what the specific component name.  Should be something like com_mycomponent.

Comment: @BrianBolli thank you for you response, I went to the menu item handling the view and I noticed that the module is called: com_community. I didn't installed it. somebody else did it. Have you heard about this module before? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, com_community is for JomSocial.  Sounds like an issue they need to resolve.  If you're able to, try assigning the same menu view to another hidden menu and try accessing directly.  I would also disabled SEF in the Joomla Global Configuration and see if the page loads then.

Comment: Thank you @BrianBolli I disabled SEF and now I can see the page! But the pictures that it suppose to display are not displayed there anymore :(. There's also an additional detail here: The section that contained that error was a section with the photos and I had a section with videos too but the videos were displaying right now I can't see any of them, so it seems like there's some issue with the component that is handling just the photos. But I'm not sure how to get that component to work again :(

Comment: You need to contact the developers to resolve this, but before you do that go to the Extension Manager > Updates view in back end and make sure there are not any updates available you could install.

Comment: Thank you @BrianBolli for your help. I already checked if there are any new updates for this extension and there's no currently updates for this one. Also, I contacted them via email but I'm still not sure if they are going to be able to help me because I'm not a registered member with them. Anyways, I check out this page that looks similar to the problem and I'm having https://www.sourcecoast.com/forums/jfbconnect/jfbconnect-joomla-17-25-support/3139-500-controller-communityindexphpcontroller-not-found But is not clear to me yet what the answer to his issue was.

Comment: It seems like there was a problem in his code but it doesn't say what file he went to.